# JS and CSS cache busting for SharePoint Online master pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, css, custom-masterpage, cache

How can JS/CSS cache busting be implemented for SharePoint Online in a master page? Other methods detailed on StackExchange do not work as SPO developers do not have access to the _layouts folder to store their custom JS/CSS files. I currently store my custom JS/CSS files in a read-only document library that everyone has access to. Some have posted about using a CDN, but there must be something easier.

Of course this can be manually accomplished by appending a "?v=[randomstring]" to your script filename but that isn't a best practice.

Ideally, I would like to utilize the OOTB cache management that SPO uses for its scripts where it adds a version number parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That OOTB cache management is done Server-side..

and with SPO.. Microsoft owns and maintains the Server

So you have to fix it Client-Side, like UserCustomActions (because they execute way before your Masterpage scripts) loading your files dynamically

first Google hit:
http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml

Comment: So really it sounds like I should avoid the masterpage completely for loading scripts, use the method from the link you provided, and append a random string to my scripts to always bust the cache. Do you agree?

Comment: Not messing with the MasterPage has been preferred practice since UserCustomActions were released in SP2010. This is from my own learnings a year ago: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/178337/can-usercustomactions-run-on-a-web-only

Comment: This Chrome Extension helps with UserCustomActions: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sp-editor/ecblfcmjnbbgaojblcpmjoamegpbodhd/related?hl=en

Comment: Good extension - thanks. It may be better to use a custom client side solution (as you suggested earlier) in this case to bust the cache. I tried adding some JS code directly in the extension - and it works - but it breaks the removal of that specific scriptlink.

Comment: I think the extension can only set the ScriptLink (to any https location you want), you need other code to set ScriptSrc